# Bootstrap active button and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails 4 app withat I have a bootstrap nav menu. The html is looking like...

```
<ul class="nav">
<li>
<a href="/tickets">Tickets</a>
</li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
```

...and I'd like to do this with javascript with something like...

## app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
  $('ul li').click( function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  });
```

...but no worky! What am I missing?

## EDIT

Change JS to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul li').click( function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the javascript code in [document ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul li').click( function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

Update: with event delegation so that the click event gets executed for modified elements:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul.nav').on('click', 'li', function(evt) {
    $(this).removeClass('active').siblings().addClass('active');
  });
});
```

Comment: You on it Vee! But still no worky. No errors in JS console. Added your edit above.

Comment: @Lumbee, what isn't working?  `classes` not added/removed?  Try just `$(this).addClass('active')` first, that should give you some clue.

Comment: Yeah, looks like the class is just not being set. Will keep looking at it and post back. I can manually set the class on an indivigual li and see the active result.

Comment: @Lumbee, try removing then adding: `$(this).removeClass('active').siblings().addClass('active');`

Comment: I think the issue may be with the  $('ul li').click. When I do this http://pastie.org/8992322, I only get the alert on the first click, then nothing else. Here is source http://pastie.org/8992344.

Comment: The issue must be related to event delegation if it only works the first time.  Are you replacing the content of the `nav` with javascript anywhere?  I'll add the code with delegated `click` event for you to try.

Comment: Looks like rails folks are doing it this way with an if statement in the layout http://pastie.org/8992361.

Comment: That should be fine because you'll be executing this javascript on the client after that erb renders.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get the JS to work. I used if statements in my layout file like this...

## app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="brand" href="/"><%= image_tag("logo-mini.png", :alt => "Tech Logo") %></a>
          <div class="nav-collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="<%= 'active' if current_page?(tickets_path) %>"><%= link_to "Tickets",
                                      tickets_path %></li>
              <li class="<%= 'active' if current_page?(instructors_path) %>"><%= link_to "Instructors",
                                      instructors_path %></li>
              <li class="<%= 'active' if current_page?(tutors_path) %>"><%= link_to "Tutors", tutors_path %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Log Out", logout_path %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "About", '/about' %></li>
          </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```